# How to force text/html mime type using PeopleSoft SendMail()

Tags: email, mime-types, sendmail, peoplesoft

I am trying to send an html formatted email using SendMail() in PeopleCode. What I am trying to do is very a basic html email (e.g. bolded text, a href tags, etc).

We recently upgraded to PeopleTools 8.52

When I use the default SendMail() example from PeopleBooks, The email is sent as plain text, regardless of the fact that I specified the content type as "text/html".

```
Local string &MAIL_CC, &MAIL_TO, &MAIL_BCC, &MAIL_SUBJECT, &MAIL_TITLES, &MAIL_TEXT, &MAIL_FILES, &MAIL_FROM, &REPLYTO, &SENDER;
Local number &MAIL_FLAGS;
&MAIL_FLAGS = 0;
&MAIL_TO = "laurie_thomas@peoplesoft.com";
&MAIL_CC = "";
&MAIL_BCC = "";
&MAIL_SUBJECT = "Testing SendMail - Are you receiving Attachment?";
&MAIL_TEXT = "This is a test for SendMail function";
&MAIL_FILES = "/data9/ps/e841g2bp/lat/attach.txt";
&MAIL_TITLES = "";
&MAIL_FROM = "peoplesoft@peoplesoft.com";
&MAIL_SEP = ";";
&CONTTYPE = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8";
&REPLYTO = "lthomas@peoplesoft.com";
&SENDER = "00972@peoplesoft.com";
&RET = SendMail(&MAIL_FLAGS, &MAIL_TO, &MAIL_CC, &MAIL_BCC, &MAIL_SUBJECT, &MAIL_TEXT, &MAIL_FILES, &MAIL_TITLES, &MAIL_FROM, &MAIL_SEP, &CONTTYPE, &REPLYTO,&SENDER);
If &RET <> 0 Then
MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "Return code from SendMail=" | &RET);
End-If;
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this is a documented bug observed by Oracle (Bug:13714374). This occurs when upgrading from PeopleTools 8.51 to 8.52 (which is why it happened to us).

Solution from Oracle:

> This Bug Fixed in the PT 8.52.08 patch, which became available on
>   05/24/2012